# Mac clients intermittently wait minutes to connect to SMB shares

Tags: mac, server-message-block, slow-connection, windows-server-2008-r2

My Mac OS X (10.6 & 10.7) clients all intermittently but frequently experience extremely slow connection times to my Windows 2008R2 shares. From the Go To Server menu, they can enter an smb:// path either in FQDN or IP and connect, but encounter a delay up to 20 minutes or more. Once the share is mounted, performance is fine. I remain baffled.

Things I've tried:

1. disabling mDNS broadcast
2. Setting IPv6 to inactive
3. changing the mdns_timeout to 1 and 0
4. setting the TCP delayed ACK to 0

Thanks to all!

Comment: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110430173901534

Answer (score 0):

Packet captures can go a fair way towards identifying the problem. Delays like this can come from TCP delays to higher level protocol delays. In the past I've had Mac clients unable to map drives to Server 2008 Failover Cluster volumes because of a bug in the anti-virus software on the 2008 servers. AV software can get in the way, it's worth trying disabling it briefly and seeing if that affects the mapping performance.